# Why is my react form not working on codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, codesandbox

I created a simple form here https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-frog-7squw

It says You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`.

But there is an onChange handler being passed, so I don't understand. In addition the page reloads when I hit submit, even though preventDefault() is called

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
const { str, handleChange, handleSubmit } = this.state;
```

`handleChange` and `handleSubmit` are not part of the state, but are instance methods, so you can pass them like so:

```
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form str={str} onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
        <Table />
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 25 you do:

```
const { str, handleChange, handleSubmit } = this.state;
```

Because of this, `handleChange` will be bound to `this.state.handleChange` which will be undefined as you have no property `handleChange` in your state.

You also forgot to pass the prop `name` to your `Table`-component.

I forked your code and updated it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-meninsky-y1sgh

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct Code for you:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/styles.css";

import Form from "./components/Form";
import Table from "./components/Table";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { str: "", desc: false };
    console.log(4444);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this); //<-- this binding
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ str: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { str } = this.state; // <-- FIXED THIS
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form str={str} onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
        <Table />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```